# Add a new column in R with presence/absence info

Tags: r

Hel lo I have a dataframe such as :

```
Col1 Col2
A 23
B NA
C 21
D 2
E NA
F 9
```

and I would like to add a new Col3 with presence/absence info (1/0)
If the number in col2 >=1 I put 1
If NA I put 0

and get :

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A 23 1
B NA 0
C 21 1
D 2 1
E NA 0
F 9 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign `Col3` as 1 if `col2` is greater than equal to 1 and is not `NA`.

```
df$Col3 <- +(df$Col2 >= 1 & !is.na(df$Col2)) 
df

#  Col1 Col2 Col3
#1    A   23    1
#2    B   NA    0
#3    C   21    1
#4    D    2    1
#5    E   NA    0
#6    F    9    1
```

`+` at the beginning converts logical values `TRUE`/`FALSE` to integer values `1`/`0`.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Col2 = c(23L, NA, 21L, 2L, 
NA, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another tidy way might be

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df,
   Col3 = ifelse(Col2 %in% NA,0,1)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(Col3 = as.integer(Col2 >=1 & !is.na(Col2)))
#  Col1 Col2 Col3
#1    A   23    1
#2    B   NA    0
#3    C   21    1
#4    D    2    1
#5    E   NA    0
#6    F    9    1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Col2 = c(23L, NA, 21L, 2L, 
NA, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```